# Signal R concurrent connection issue

Tags: asp.net, connection, signalr, chat

I am using Signal R to develop a chat in my webpage. I am having a problem with simultaneous connections. When two browsers connect to chat at the same time (well there is a small difference in seconds sure), the connection function treats the requests at the same time (not one after the other), and in each chat a clients name is replicated ( so the connect function connects same client twice )

How do I fix this?
Thanx in advance!

I am adding the code for Connect function and the Scripts I use onConnected and OnNewuserConnected(which is where users are added to the list of users)

```
public void Connect(string userName, int? pid)
    {
        var id = Context.ConnectionId;
        var projectId = pid.ToString();

        if (ConnectedUsers.Where(x => x.ConnectionId == id).Where(y => y.ProjectId == projectId).Count() == 0)
        {
            ConnectedUsers.Add(new UserDetail { ConnectionId = id, UserName = userName, ProjectId = projectId });
            // send to caller
            Clients.Caller.onConnected(id, userName, ConnectedUsers, CurrentMessage, projectId);

            // send to all except caller client
            Clients.AllExcept(id).onNewUserConnected(id, userName, projectId);

            // add user to group
            Groups.Add(id, projectId);

        }
```

And here is the Javascript on the client side

```
    // Calls when user successfully logged in
chatHub.client.onConnected = function (id, userName, allUsers, messages, pid) {

    var inRoles = [];
    //// Add All Users
    $("li.userinRole_" + pid).each(function (index) {
        inRoles.push($(this).text());
    });
    $('#hdId_' + pid).val(id);
    $('#hdUserName_' + pid).val(userName);
    $('#spanUser_' + pid).html(userName);
    AddUser(chatHub, id, userName, pid);
    if ($.inArray(userName, inRoles) === -1) {
        console.log(userName + ": è un user online che non ha un ruolo in progetto ")
        for (var i = 0; i < allUsers.length; i++) {
            if ($.inArray(allUsers[i].UserName, inRoles) !== -1 && allUsers[i].ProjectId == pid) {
                AddUser(chatHub, allUsers[i].ConnectionId, allUsers[i].UserName, pid);
            }
        }

    } else {

        console.log(userName + ": è un user online con ruolo in progetto")
        for (i = 0; i < allUsers.length; i++) {
            if (allUsers[i].ProjectId == pid && allUsers[i].UserName != userName) {
                AddUser(chatHub, allUsers[i].ConnectionId, allUsers[i].UserName, pid);
            }

        }
    }

    // Add Existing Messages
    for (i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        if (messages[i].Group == pid) {
            AddMessage(messages[i].UserName, messages[i].Message, pid);
        }
    }

}

// On New User Connected
chatHub.client.onNewUserConnected = function (id, name, pid) {
    debugger;
    var inRoles = [];
    //// Add All Users
    $("li.userinRole_" + pid).each(function (index) {
        inRoles.push($(this).text());
    });

        if (($.inArray(name, inRoles) !== -1) && ($.inArray($("#currentUser_" + pid).attr("value"), inRoles) == -1)) {
            console.log(name + ": ha un ruolo in questo progetto, add user cikli 1 new user");
            AddUser(chatHub, id, name, pid);
        }
        else if (($.inArray(name, inRoles) == -1) && ($.inArray($("#currentUser_" + pid).attr("value"), inRoles) !== -1)) {
            console.log(name + ": non ha un ruolo,add user cikli 2 new user");
            AddUser(chatHub, id, name, pid);

        }
        else if (($.inArray(name, inRoles) !== -1) && ($.inArray($("#currentUser_" + pid).attr("value"), inRoles) !== -1)) {
            console.log(name + ": non ha un ruolo in progetto " + pid);
            AddUser(chatHub, id, name, pid);
        }
}
```

The problem is when two users connect at the same time. The connect function fills the ConnectedUsers List (and it accounts for two users), these users are added by the javascript at the onConnect function (they both add to the chat since they are both connected to the same projectId). But,appart from doing this, after the onConnected function is called, the onNewUserConnected function adds one more user to each chat...

Comment: Without looking at the code we won't be able to help you. Can you post the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

What is calling the .net Connect method? It is possible there is a flaw in the flow of your code. So, if you are calling Connect( ) from, let's say in a constructor of a MVC Controller, then I can see how you are receiving 2 messages (it appears to be making a connection 2x). So again, where is the Connect( ) being called from?